# ruby on rails check if value exist in array always returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, include, exists

I am trying to check if a set pset(aka problem set) exist in an array in order to display the correct page but the following code always returns true...

```
  def c
    allowed_psets = [1]
    pset_id = 12323

    if allowed_psets.include?(pset_id)
        //do something here
    else
        render_404//error
    end
  end
```

do i miss something here?

Comment: Maybe you have got problems with `render_404`? code is valid

Comment: @fl00r that code works fine if i put it on top since it simply renders 404.html from public dir... there is no problem there... the problem is that it always goes inside the true condition when it shouldnt...

Comment: it works fine. problem with 404

Comment: ok, show what will return this:
`if allowed_psets.include?(pset_id); puts allowed_psets.inspect; puts pset_id.inspect; render_404; end ...`

Comment: @fl00r i simply get the 404.html page rendered and nothing else... @ Aayush Khandelwal weird...

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: maybe in `//do something here` is non valid code?

Comment: I want to display a 404 if the pset_id does not exist in the array...

Comment: " i simply get the 404.html page rendered and nothing else... " sounds good?

Comment: seems to work now...weird, answering with a bit changed action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code:

```
  def c

    allowed_psets = [
        1
    ]

    pset_id = params[:pset_id]

    if allowed_psets.include?(pset_id.to_i)
        #do something here
    else
        render_404#error
    end

  end
```

Comment: not sure... maybe something in the routes... i debugged the params sent to the browser and somehow it got fixed...